# Google safebrowsing post requests

Tags: browser, javascript, privacy

My browser often sends some weird post requests like this:

```
POST http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/downloads?client=navclient-auto-ffox&appver=22.0&pver=2.2&wrkey=XXXXXX HTTP/1.1
Host: safebrowsing.clients.google.com
User-Agent: XXXX
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length: 110
Content-Type: text/plain
Cookie: PREF=ID=XXXXXXX:FF=XXX:LD=XXX:TM=XXXX:LM=XXXX...........

Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache


-------------------------------------------(body...)
goog-phish-shavar;a:XXXXXXX:mac
goog-malware-shavar;a:XXXXXXXXX:mac
```

What is this? Is it some kind of user tracking JavaScript running when I use Google with no `noscript`, or what is the origin and purpose of this? Can I turn this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safe Browsing is a service provided by Google that enables applications to check URLs against Google's constantly updated lists of suspected phishing and malware pages.

[Source](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/01/all-about-safe-browsing.html)

Disable phishing and malware detection:

1. Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
2. Select **Settings**.
3. Click **Show advanced settings** and find the "Privacy" section.
4. Deselect the "Enable phishing and malware protection" checkbox.

[Source](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=99020&hl=en)